# vector comparison issues with data from csv file

Tags: r

I am trying to compare the two vectors below. The values I pull from the csv file though do not give the correct answer. If I try this with two hardcoded vectors it works perfectly. Why?

Code:

```
dataIn=read.csv("MY FILE HERE"sep=",",header=TRUE)
fromCSV<-c(dataIn[2:2,24:27]) #values: 1,1,2,2
inputInts<-c(1,2,2,1)

which(!mapply(identical,fromCSV,inputInts))# I expected: 1,2 as output
```

Results:

```
title1  title2   title3   title4
  1       2         3       4
```

My dataset is a lot larger then this, I cut it down to 4 for simplicity. My end goal is to get the number of values that are exact matches between the two vectors (answer 2)

Comment: Are you looking for `sum(fromCSV == inputInts)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=1:5
y=c(1,2,3,4,4)
x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
y
[1] 1 2 3 4 4
x==y
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
sum(x==y)
[1] 4
```

using "==" to do a comparison returns a boolean of true or false, you can then sum them up and any TRUE will = 1, False will = 0

This is because sum is a numeric function and will convert the boolean data to numeric i.e.

```
as.numeric(x==y)
[1] 1 1 1 1 0
```

You say it works when hardcoded, have you checked that the data structures are the same?

Comment: That was my problem, the data structures werent the same. How would you generalize this to get a column of results, rather than just one if given multiple inputs?

Comment: how are your multiple inputs structured? can you please be a bit more specific

Comment: I solved the issue by using score.multiple.choice, Thanks though!